# How to convert data from pandas.core.series.Series to integer list python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

[image]

Hi,

I am working with pandas library. df is dataframe variable. The data shown in image is stored in variable df and `type(df)` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`
Now I want to process df in such a way that my output should be in integer list form.

E.g:

```
output = [5473282,9027153,9027164, 5473240,5473210,12982466,12982490,12982500,5473272,5473404,5473398,5473240,5473400,8927739,54734185473414,5473240,9552694,9552694,9552694,9552694,9552694,9552694,8945332,8949514,8945334,8949516,9552694,8945263,8949506,8927743,12982466,8927742,12982490]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `df.sum()` not do what you're wanting?

Comment: Oh it worked!. Thank you so much.